# How do I identify the company that hosts my website when the hosting was set up by somebody else?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, cloud-hosting

So me and my friend created and funded a website for a business venture. However due to some complications I no longer want to be part of the venture. My friend on the other hand will not remove my name from the website so I want to contact the host to force my friend to remove my name. The problem is my friend is the technical one and set things up so I have no idea who the host is, and every host finding tool has come up with nothing. I eventually used webhostinghero.com and they it said the domain is being hosted by 8 providers prntscr.com/nnb0he

I have two questions.

1. Is webhostinghero.com reliable?
2. Is it possible to link multiple providers to one domain to mislead people? (I highly doubt my friend is willing to spend money on 8 hosting providers for one website so he must be using some service to protect the name of the host)

Comment: Thank you for the edit Stephen Ostermiller.

Comment: You should check the DNS `A` and `NS` records on the domain. Where does your name appear? It is actually on the website? And/or associated with billing?

Comment: Thanks, I will check. My name appears on the website since I wrote some content.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx?  It will look up the `A` and `NS` records @DocRoot mentioned.  It has several tools to help lookup further information.   Look for the tiny hyperlinks across the middle of the page - run dns check first and then dns propogation.  You should be able to find everything you need, including your hosting company.

You said you weren't technical, so let me help with some of the things you might see when looking up your domain.

The `A` records define the servers that are physically hosting something:  website, maybe email, etc.  The `NS` records define what servers/vendors are resolving your Internet name like example.com to an IP address (like 10.1.1.1).

`NS` records may actually point to a different company, but wouldn't have any content, other than maybe your name and address for identifying who is responsible for the domain.  The `A` and `CNAME` records would be where your web pages reside.

If you see `CNAME`, it acts like an alias and points to your `A` records.  You might see multiple records, but the only records you should need to look at are the `A` records

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't know if it is reliable. I haven't used it before and now, when I tried it with one of my websites, it returned an error. Maybe just google "find web host info" and use some other tool? I then tried [hostingchecker.com](https://hostingchecker.com) (the first in google search results for me) and it was ok.
2. I don't think it's possible but can it be that you misinterpret the results? Can you provide a screenshot where you hide sensitive data but we can get the idea where and how those 8 providers appear?

Comment: It is possible I misunderstood it. Here is the screen shot but I cropped out some information for privacy. http://prntscr.com/nnb0he

Comment: it's better you add this image to the question